# How do you save the rendering of a tiled map to an image?

Tags: java, libgdx, file, tiles

Im currently using LibGDX and drawing a tiledmap with the OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer. Is there a way to save one rendering and put it into some file as an image? If you know of a method that doesnt use OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer, thats ok too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Taking-a-Screenshot

You might also want to try FrameBufferObjects

https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/FrameBufferObjects

(Note the link near the top of this article to the LibGDX version)

Good luck!

Comment: Usually link-only answers do not age well, which makes them not ideal. It would be better if together with the link you also provided some information of how it works, or some minimum steps to achieve the desired results with something like "Click here for more complicated examples" at the end. Keep in mind the future users that might encounter the same problem and find this question :)